# Warning CS0618: 'ComplexTypeModelBinder' is obsolete

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0

In .NET Core 3 I extended `ComplexTypeModelBinder` class to create custom model binder for a specific class.

Main target was to override creation of model instance via `CreateModel` method.

```cs
public MyModelBinder: ComplexTypeModelBinder
{
    // Constructor here...
    
    protected override object CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Create model instance based on custom condition.
    }

}
```

After an upgrade to .NET 5, I'm receiving a compilation warning to replace `ComplexTypeModelBinder` with `ComplexObjectModelBinder`:

> warning CS0618: 'ComplexTypeModelBinder' is obsolete: 'This type is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. Use ComplexObjectModelBinder instead.'

The problem is that `ComplexObjectModelBinder` is sealed class and `CreateModel` method is `internal`, so subclass approach cannot work any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I settled for is to create class `MyModelBinder` which implement `IModelBinder` interface and acts as a wrapper around `ComplexObjectModelBinder`. `ComplexObjectModelBinder` is passed in `MyModelBinder` as constructor parameter.

Same approach is used for `MyModelBinderProvider` and `ComplexObjectModelProvider`.

Later, instead of overriding `CreateMethod` of `ComplexObjectModelBinder`, which is not possible in .NET 5, just assign `bindingContext.Model` in the wrapper method `BindAsyncModel` of `MyModelBinder`, before passing the `bindingContext` to `ComplexObjectModelBinder`'s `BindAsyncModel`. This will make `ComplexObjectModelBinder` use model that is passed in, instead of creating default new instance.

```cs
public class MyModelBinder: IModelBinder
{
    private readonly ComplexObjectModelBinder _binder;
    public MyModelBinder(ComplexObjectModelBinder binder)
    {
        _binder = binder;
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        MyModel myModel = // custom instantiation logic here
        bindingContext.Model = myModel;
        return _binder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}
```

For the registration of the custom model binder provider, first we find existing, automatically registered `ComplexObjectBinderProvider`, use it in costructor of `MyModelBinderProvider` and then insert `MyModelBinderProvider` in front of `ComplexObjectBinderProvider`.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options => {
        // more configurations here...

        var bindingProvider = options.ModelBinderProviders.First(provider =>
            provider is ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider) as ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider;

        var indexOf = options.ModelBinderProviders.IndexOf(bindingProvider);

        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(indexOf, new MyModelBinderProvider(bindingProvider));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `MyModelBinderProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's own comment at github, this type is marked obsolete for internal use only, it won't be removed:

> The obsoletion is to indicate the type isn't used by the framework, ***but we're going to leave it as-is***.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33545#issuecomment-861689903

---

However, if you're like me and hate warnings in the build log here's an improved and more complete answer based on @Nenad's . Read the comments

```cs
//custom binder
public class MyObjectBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private IModelBinder _defaultBinder;

    public MyObjectBinder(IModelBinder defaultBinder) => _defaultBinder = defaultBinder;

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        bindingContext.Model =  //your custom model creation

        return _defaultBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext); //bind the properties using default binder
    }
}

//provider to registering the binder above
public class MyObjectBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    private ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider _fallbackProvider;

    public MyObjectBinderProvider(ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider fallbackProvider) => _fallbackProvider = fallbackProvider;

    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        //make sure it's added for your type only
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(MyObject))
        {
            //pass the default "complex object binder" to our custom binder
            return new MyObjectBinder(_fallbackProvider.GetBinder(context));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, in Startup.cs let's add this binder:

```cs
services.AddMvc(option =>
{
    //use ".Last: for performance b/c CustomObjectModelBinder is usually at the very end
    var fallbackProvider = option
        .ModelBinderProviders
        .Last(p => p is ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider)
        as ComplexObjectModelBinderProvider;

    option.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new MyObjectBinderProvider(fallbackProvider)); //insert at 0
}
```